# 1.16 * 100 in xslt produces 115.99999999999999

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

If I try to multiply in xslt 2.0 `1.6 * 100` it will result `115.99999999999999`

How to force it to result `116`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force your code to round it like so:

```
 <xsl:template match="Number">
    <Result>
       <Total amount="{round(format-number(1.60, '#.00')*100)}"/>
   </Result>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 and `version="2.0"` in your stylesheet and the XPath expression contains number literals like in your sample `1.6 * 100`?

Because in that case you should get a precise result, for instance with

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:value-of select="1.16 * 100"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.4 outputs `116`.

The result is different with `version="1.0"` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:value-of select="1.16 * 100"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get a warning "Running an XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 processor" and the output `115.99999999999999`.

So with an XSLT 2.0 processor and `version="2.0"` in your code you should not have the problem, the literals represent `xs:decimal` numbers.

If you process XML input then it is different with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:value-of select="a * b"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the input

```
<root>
  <item>
    <a>1.16</a>
    <b>100</b>
  </item>
</root>
```

you get `115.99999999999999`.

In that case you should make sure the processor works with `xs:decimal`s by doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(a) * xs:decimal(b)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

floatpoint in action, so there is tolerance errors : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html